# Hi, how can i make the OPTION have a value inside it? and make it change the message as selecting another option?

Tags: javascript

I want `var s` to receive the option value, to be able to do the division without having to put the direct number in the var, for example: `n1 / value.usd` (eur = 5.58) and after that make the `<h5>` change the text according to the option selected example:

- USD - Dollar =
  **'1 US dollar equal to 5.58 Brazilian real'**
- EUR - Euro =
  **'1 Euro equals 6.69 Brazilian Real'**

  I am studying the DOM, so I am trying to do this project, any advice is welcome

```html
<body>
    <div id="tabela">
        <h1 id="title">Conversor de Real para Dólar</h1>
        <div id="area">
            <strong>R$</strong><input type="number" name="txtn1" id="txtn1"> PARA:
            <select name="txtn2" id="txtn2">
                <option value = "usd">USD - Dólar</option> <!--The option that i want put a value-->
                <option value="eur">EUR - Euro</option>
                <option value="gbp">GBP - Libra Esterlina</option>
                <option value="cad">CAD - Dólar Canadense</option>
                <option value="jpy">JPY - Yen</option>
                <option value="cny">CNY - Yuan</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="CONVERTER" onclick="converter()">
            <div id="resul">Clique em <strong>converter</strong> para ver o resultado em <strong>U$</strong>!</div>
            <h5>1 Dólar americano igual a 5,58 Real brasileiro</h5> <!--The text that i want change conform the option-->
        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
```

**JS CODE**

```js
function converter(){
    let tn1 = document.querySelector('input#txtn1');
    let resul = document.querySelector('div#resul');
    let n1 = Number(tn1.value);
    let s = n1/5.58
    resul.innerHTML = ` Você tinha: <strong>R$${n1.toFixed(2).replace(".",",").toLocaleString('pt-BR',{style: 'currency', currency:'BRL'})}</strong><br>
    Agora você tem: <strong>U$${s.toFixed(2).replace(".",",").toLocaleString('USA',{style: 'currency', currency:'USD'})}</strong><br>
    Clique em <strong>converter</strong> para converter novamente.`
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It's not entirely clear what you' re asking, since you seem to be asking multiple questions at once. Please try to edit your question to add details and clarity, to help us better help you. You may want to have a look at [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add an event listener and listen for change..

```js
const txtn2 = document.getElementById('txtn2');

txtn2.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  console.log(e.target.value)
})



function converter(option){console.log(option)}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="tabela">
        <h1 id="title">Conversor de Real para Dólar</h1>
        <div id="area">
            <strong>R$</strong><input type="number" name="txtn1" id="txtn1"> PARA:
            <select name="txtn2" id="txtn2">
                <option value = "usd">USD - Dólar</option> <!--The option that i want put a value-->
                <option value="eur">EUR - Euro</option>
                <option value="gbp">GBP - Libra Esterlina</option>
                <option value="cad">CAD - Dólar Canadense</option>
                <option value="jpy">JPY - Yen</option>
                <option value="cny">CNY - Yuan</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="CONVERTER" onclick="converter()">
            <div id="resul">Clique em <strong>converter</strong> para ver o resultado em <strong>U$</strong>!</div>
            <h5>1 Dólar americano igual a 5,58 Real brasileiro</h5> <!--The text that i want change conform the option-->
        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
```

Comment: So, and now it's just give value for the `txtn2`? cuz in the output shows NaN